# Use Outlook distribution list as SharePoint security group

Tags: security, outlook

I got across this question, is it possible to use an **Outlook** distribution list as **SharePoint** security group? Let's say that I have a mail group and I need to use it as the **Members** group of one of my SharePoint sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, you can use AD Users and AD Groups if you do not use a custom Claims-provider

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use Outlook distribution list as a SharePoint security group. However you can convert the Outlook distribution list to an Active Directory Security group. Next you can import the Active Directory security group to SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds as a solution, but how do you convert those lists? I'm not asking for detailed description, but where it should be made?